# tcsh: How to clear command line arguments after use?

Tags: tcsh

I have a script called release.csh that takes in command line arguments. This script calls 'source sourceme' where sourceme is another script of which I have no control over. The command line arguments passed to 'release.csh' end up getting used by 'sourceme' even though I don't explicitly pass command line arguments to 'sourceme'. So how can I clear command line arguments inside release.csh so that it doesn't mess up 'sourceme'?

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/tcsh

# The release.csh script takes in the release version as a cmd line arg
set releaseVer = $1

# But when I call the 'sourceme' script, the cmd line args get passed
# So I want to clear the cmd line args here
source ConfigFiles/sourceme
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tcsh's command-line arguments are in the variable `$argv` (also visible as `$1`, `$2`, etc.).

To clear them:

```
set argv = ()
```

([*obligatory link*](https://web.mit.edu/ghudson/info/csh.whynot))

Comment: This worked. Thanks also for the supplementary link.